# How can I stop subversion from freezing when connecting over a VPN?

Tags: svn, openvpn

I'm trying to `svn up` a subversion repository on Windows 7 x64. It's set up to connect via the `svn://` protocol and should be accessed via a VPN (OpenVPN). There's an entry in my local `hosts` file mapping the repository's host name to a network address on the VPN network.

This all works fine when I'm at work using the same laptop.

I'm working from home today and trying to connect. When I do `svn up`, either with Collabnet's svn or TortoiseSVN, a few files will transfer okay and then the UI will freeze (looks like it would if it was just taking a long time to download, but doesn't ever seem to get there). I then have to kill it and do a `svn cleanup` before trying again.

Any idea what might be wrong? I temporarily disabled the firewalls on my wireless router and in Windows, but still the same thing happened. This is incredibly frustrating!

**Edit:** Some (but not all) of my colleagues have the same problem. The suggestion is that it might depend on which ISP we're using. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Or, failing that, is there some way to make the subversion executable more tolerant of packet loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touch wood, adding the following setting to my OpenVPN configuration file seems to have sorted it out:

```
mssfix 1200
```